# Up to Date for Leil Haseder

Tags: support, haggadah-project

How can I be sure that I download the last version of the mi yodeya's Hagada?
I see multiple posts and it is not clear for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest version will always be linked to from http://s.tk/miyodeya.

Comment: The answer was from mbloch and suddenly the author has changed, what is the explanation?

Comment: @kouty mbloch answered, then I answered, then mbloch's answer was deleted.